# Wrong use of Zorn's lemma in equivalence of noetherian properties.

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

I was wondering wether the proof of the follwing statement I found online was correct.

Let $M$ be an $R$-Module ($R$ commutative and unital).

(a) Every ascending sequence $N_0 \subset N_1 \subset \cdots$ of submodules of $M$ terminates.

(b) Every non-empty set $\mathfrak{M}$ of submodules of $M$ has a maximal element.

Then (a) implies (b).

*proof.* We can apply Zorn's lemma to $(\mathfrak{M},\subset)$ since any ascending chain terminates and hence is bounded in $\mathfrak{M}$. Therefore there is a maximal element.

My objections is that in order to use Zorn's lemma we need to show that any totally ordered subset of $\mathfrak{M}$ has an upper bound in $\mathfrak{M}$. But in the above proof this fact is only estabished for countable totally ordered subsets. Is there a way to bypass this problem? I know a proof of the above using the axiom of dependent choice. So I'm not asking for a general proof, rather for a proof using Zorn's lemma in this straightforward way.

Comment: An uncountable chain would imply the existence of a countable chain (simply take the first countable part of that chain). But there are no countable chains and so we can't have an uncountable chain either.

Comment: @memerson: The uncountable chain is not _a priori_ well-ordered (unless you look past the usual black-box statement of Zorn's lemma and dissect its proof), so "take the initial part" won't necessarily work. But you can apply Zorn's lemma separately to the set of ordinal-indexed subchains to show that every chain in a partial order has either a maximal element or an $\omega$-shaped subchain.

Comment: Just to clarify: By a $\omega$-shaped subchain you mean a sequence $(x_i)_i$, $x_i \leq x_{i+1}$ that never terminates? 
So if we wanted to prove this statement using only Zorn's lemma we esentailly had to use it twice.

Comment: @vava123: Correct. (By the way, it now strikes me that "ordinal-indexed subchains" is overkill for this purpose -- it's enough to use the lemma on increasing partial functions from $\mathbb N$ to the original chain).

Comment: @Troposphere, you are totally right. I spaced and mixed up totally ordered subsets with well-ordered subsets for some reason.

Comment: @Troposphere Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Remark: The implication may be proven by contradiction, without Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Yes I think you mean the prove i was mentioning above using dependent choice. By assuming there is no maximal element in $\mathfrak{M}$ dependent choices gives us a strictliy ascending chain $N_0 \subset N_1 \subset \cdots $ of submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objection to the quoted proof is valid -- the proof is at best leaving out some details of how to deal with chains that are not simple ascending sequences.

We can salvage it by instead doing this:

**Lemma.** Let $P$ be any partial order. Then $P$ contains either a maximal element or an infinite ascending sequence.

**Proof.** Apply Zorn's lemma to the set of partial increasing functions $\mathbb N\to P$ (ordered by set inclusion, as it is common in Zorn applications). We get a maximal such function. If its domain has a largest element, then its image must be a maximal element of $P$ (or we could extend the function). Otherwise the image of the function is an infinite ascending sequence.

Now since $\mathfrak M$ is partially ordered but doesn't contain an infinite ascending sequence, it must have a maximal element.

If you want preserve the particular step "apply Zorn's lemma to $(\mathfrak M,\subseteq)$", then I think you'll need something like the above lemma to deal with an *arbitrary* chain anyway.

---

Sometimes Zorn's lemma is stated in a variant where the premise is not "every chain has an upper bound", but "every well-ordered subset has an upper bound". This is apparently stronger than the usual statement of the lemma, but is actually what the usual proof from the axiom of choice proves, so the strengthening is actually harmless (since standard Zorn $\Rightarrow$ axiom of choice $\Rightarrow$ strenghtened Zorn).

If you're using this strengthened Zorn's lemma instead, you can use Memerson's suggestion (from a comment) to take the initial $\omega$ elements of the well-ordered subset to get a contradiction with the noetherian property if the well-ordered subset doesn't have a maximum.

Comment: The statement in your lemma is not exclusive, right? So one could just delete the ‚either‘. And thanks for the additional information regarding the strengthened version of Zorn’s lemma by the way.

Comment: @vava123: Correct, they can both be true of the same order. In my experience "either-or" does not signal exclusivity any more than "or" itself does; both wordings are inclusive by default in mathematics.